# Method naming in MVVM design pattern

Tags: android, ios, mvvm, architecture

I have a two option how to name a view model method, for example for refreshing:

1. onRefreshButtonPressed
2. refresh

could you please explain which is correct?

What I confused about:

- in first case view model knows that some refresh button exists, hence it know about view and coupled with view
- in second case view can decide what method to call, hence contains a some logic

Answer (score 0):

Usually, methods names are verbs, so in this case

`refresh` is more convenient.

For `onRefreshButtonPressed` seems like Callback. It's similar to `onClickListener` or any callback.